# Javascript Moment.js Change time from AM to PM

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to add 12:00 PM to an existing Moment date object. In debugging, the date object looks like this

Tues Sept 01 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0400

I am convert to a string but getting the AM after the conversion.

```
MyDate = moment(this.TestDate.format("MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A");
```

I read the moment.js docs and thought that adding the 'A' would change the AM to PM but so far it does not work. I read a few post and tried a few different version of code but so far no luck.

I would like to get the following date string after the conversion

10/10/2019 12:00 PM

Thanks

Comment: This is working as expected. 00:00:00 is 12 AM. If you want 12 PM, you need your time to be 12:00:00.

Comment: You'll need to add 12 hours to your time so that midnight (12 am) becomes midday (12 pm).

Comment: ''A would change the AM to PM" - No it doesn't. Moment.js will calculate it depending upon the given time.

Comment: 'A' will display  AM / PM (in CAPITALS)
'a' will display am/pm (in small)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding **'A'** in `format()` only **display** 'AM'/'PM'. You need to first [manipulate](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/) your date and then [display](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/) the new value.

Assuming `this.TestDate` is a moment instance :

```
MyDate = moment(this.TestDate.add('12', 'hours').format("MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A");
```

## About manipulation

Be careful about moment's manipulation, it change the moment instance inside your variable, meaning :

```
MyDate = moment('Tues Sept 01 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0400')
console.log(Mydate); // Show Tues Sept 01 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0400
MyDate2 = MyDate.add(12, 'hours');
console.log(Mydate); // Show Tues Sept 01 2019 12:00:00 GMT-0400
```